# How to apply CDC?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, change-data-capture

Please how i can apply CDC(change data capture) for database that i readed using spark and then save it as parquet into HADOOP HDFS.
this is the code:

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Ingest") \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/home.../mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar") \
        .getOrCreate()
df = spark.read\
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classicmodels") \
        .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") \
        .option("dbtable", "employees") \
        .option("user", "...") \
        .option("password", "...").load()
print(df.show())
dataframe_mysql.write.parquet("hdfs://localhost:9000/...")
```

the code return the data readed in dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Spark doesn't do change-data-capture. Neither does any batch/polling JDBC client, really
, because you're always querying the after state, not the actual change event

For this, Debezium+Kafka are frequently used, although, there are alternative options

Once data is stored in Kafka, it can then be consumed by Kafka Connect, Spark, etc.  and written as Parquet